# Copying files based on the names given in a txt file and sending them into folders based on quarters of the year

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a script that will look inside a `abc.txt` file, which consist of a list of the files having naming convention like `flow28092014`, `collateral28102014` and `trade28032014`.
For e.g.:

```
flow28092014
collateral28102014
trade28032014
```

So scripts needs to check the file name and based on their name (as their name has a date given), it should copy those files one by one to the required folders (folder name are `Q1-2015`, `Q2-2015`, `Q3-2015` and `Q4-2015`). So for e.g `abc.txt` has file from *March* then it should send them into `Q1-2015` and if `abc.txt` has file name from *June* then it should send them into `Q2-2015` folder.

Below I have given my code but it is sending all the files at the same time:

```
for %%a in ("%src%\*.*") do echo %%~na>>%ftp_file%
:: "tokens=4 delims=MT52-"
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%ftp_file%) do (
    set filename=%%A

    if !filename:~-1!==l (

        set mm=!filename:~-10,2!
        echo !mm!
        echo ctrl files: !filename!
        if !mm! GEQ 01 if !mm! LEQ 03 (
        copy %src%\%filename% %dest%\Q1-%year% )

        if !mm! GEQ 04 if !mm! LEQ 06 (
        copy %src%\%filename% %dest%\Q2-year% )

        if !mm! GEQ 07 if !mm! LEQ 09 (
        copy %src%\%filename% %dest%\Q3-%year% )        

        if !mm! GEQ 10 if !mm! LEQ 12 (
        copy %src%\%filename% %dest%\Q4-%year% )

    ) else (
        echo no match found )
)
```

Comment: Please check the value of mm. I wonder if it should be `SET mm=!filename:~-6,2!` if the format is DDMMYYYY. Or, did you omit the fact that the filenames have a three (3) character extension such as `.txt`?

Comment: 2. I'd use `set "filename=%%~nA"` to get the file name only; 2. what is `if !filename:~-1!==l` for? 3. it should read `set "mm=!filename:~-6,2!"` then; 4. I#d use `copy "%%~fA" "%dest%\Q?-*"` (supposed `%dest%` does not contain surrounding `""`); 5. the year portion of the file names (`!filename:~-4!`) is never checked against `%year%` (is this actually set correctly?); 6. your `if` logic could be way less complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
> %ftp_file% (for %%a in ("%src%\*.*") do echo %%~na)

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%ftp_file%") do (
    set "filename=%%~nA"
    set "mm=!filename:~-6,2!"
    for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%B in ("!mm!") do set "mm=%%B"
    set "yyyy=!filename:~-4!"
    if "!yyyy!"=="%year%" (

        if !mm! LEQ 3 (
            copy "%%~fA" "%dest%\Q1-%year%"
        ) else if !mm! LEQ 6 (
            copy "%%~fA" "%dest%\Q2-%year%"
        ) else if !mm! LEQ 9 (
            copy "%%~fA" "%dest%\Q3-%year%"
        ) else (
            copy "%%~fA" "%dest%\Q4-%year%"
        )
    ) else (
        echo Year does not match.
    )
)
```

1. changed line to set `filename` to get the pure name only (no extension);
2. I removed the `if !filename!:~-1!==l` query as it is confusing in the code excerpt of the question; (it can be reinserted in the final script of course;)
3. corrected extraction of month portion `mm` (due to change of `filename`);
4. adapted `copy` source as `%%~fA` is already the full path; and put destination path in between `""` (supposing `dest` does not contain any surrounding double-quotes on its own);
5. introduced check of the year portion using new variable `yyyy`;
6. simplified `if`/`else` logic for sorting the files properly;
7. in your `copy` commands you missed delayed expansion of `filename` (you stated `%filename%` instead of `!filename!`); since I used `%%~fA` as copy source, this problem is no longer present;
8. in the `Q2` copy line, there was a typo, the leading `%` in the destination was missing (`Q2-year%`);
9. improved the initial redirection syntax, moved redirection `>` out of the `for` body, so the file is written once; (formerly, the lines have been appended;)
10. removed leading zeros from `mm` using `for /f`, and also from the numeric constants in the `if` statements; this is done to do true numeric comparisons; stating leading zeros in `if` statement expressions defines to interprete the numbers as octal rather than decimal ones, but `08` and `09` are not valid octal numbers, so a string comparison was actually performed;

Answer (score 0):

```
(for %%a in ("%src%\*.*") do echo %%~na) > %ftp_file%

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%ftp_file%) do (
   set "filename=%%A"
   set /A "quarter=(1!filename:~-6,2!-101)/3+1, year=!filename:~-4!"
   copy "%src%\%%A" "%dest%\Q!quarter!-!year!"
)
```

The `set /A` command convert the month number into the appropriate year quarter. For example:

```
set "filename=trade28032014"
!filename:~-6,2!          is month number: 03
1!filename:~-6,2!-101     is month minus one without left zeros: 103-101 = 2
(2)/3+1                   is year quarter: 1
```